Clarification Help: Areas of Specialization (AOS) vs Areas of Competence (AOC)
I seem people list their AOS and AOC on their CV's, but it is not clear to me how these categories are distinguished from each other. Is the AOC the general field in which you work and the AOS your specific interests within that general field? Or does the AOS represent your research interests and the AOC your teaching abilities? Or is it something else?
Thank you for any clarity you can provide!

Interesting, I’ve never seen that on any resume I’ve reviewed.

I seem them rather regularly in theology, religious studies, and even philosophy. I don't know if they are more common than that or if the frequency I've seen them is an outlier.

In my experience they are synonymous. However, note that they are also meaningless to most people if you don't have the publications or industry experience to back up those claims.
Saying that bacterial genomics is an AOS, but not listing any relevant research or industry experience in bacterial genomics is really the same as not mentioning it at all.

I would say that area of specialization is a the particular field, subfield or a more specific designation of he area of research/studies. Area of competence is more related to your skills, which can be transferred to another area. The former are more relevant for job search in academia, where the prior knowledge of the field is of high value. The latter are more of interest in industry, where one is unlikely to work in the same specialized domain, but, provided specific skills, can readily do some useful work.
Remark: I might be influence by competences literally meaning skills in French CVs.
